# Работа поверх стандартных приложений Android

Tags: android, java

Суть такова:
Нужно вызывать стандартную звонилку и каким-то образом на ее экране ловить свайпы влево-вправо. Как реализовать такую фишку? Может можно создать какой-то невидимый слой поверх всего, который будет пропускать через себя нажатия и отлавливать свайпы?

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Тут описано как свои View поверх всего отображать http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/376170/17609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно через интенты вызвать звонилку,но свайпить ты её не сможешь.
Если надо спайпить звонилку, то нужно писать свою звонилку.

Comment: Вызвать то не проблема, проблема именно в свайпах.
Через сервис (службу) нельзя ловить свайпы на экране случайно?