# Создать ImageView, чтобы она отображалась пока работает программа

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, android-fragment, activity

Есть приложение, надо создать ImageView, чтобы она отображалась пока работает программа.

**Обновление**

В общем, есть 5 активити, надо сделать так, чтобы ImageView отображался на всех активити, до того пока работает приложение. ImageView не должен зависеть от активити. То есть когда переключаюсь между активити, то ImageView должен отображаться поверх всех активити. Короче, как Панель задач вместе с кнопкой ПУСК и треем в Windows.

Comment: @xTIGRx, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Просто тут не выйдет. Надо в каждой активити отдельно добавлять картинку в лэйуат... 

Каждый лэйаут основной брать RelativeLayout. Тогда можно будет картинку поверх остального содержимого располагать.

Comment: Я не "гоню", а высказываю своё мнение, основанное на опыте, достаточном, чтобы давать полезные советы в разработке (как минимум).

А на ссылку я бы посмотрел.

Comment: http://myfolder.ru/files/upload/?session=6428f7e0d264eff5bf88df2d6d24fd18

Comment: @xTIGRx, по ссылке фигня какая-то, пришлите ещё раз. Сейчас мне там "Подтверждение файлов" предлагают. Я хз, как скачать.

Comment: @xTIGRx, Оформляйте ответы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Comment: Посмотрел на видео. Там рекламируется планшет с интернетом. Никаких картинок особых не видел.

Comment: @KoVadim, Там картинка внизу, она отображается даже когда он в меню зашел...просмотрите этот пункт раз 10, если вы говорит что там ничего необычного нет. Картинка внизу белая такая.

Comment: Я хотя с андроидом и не знаком, но, по-моему, на том планшете специальная прошивка, модифицированная для него. Например, на моем стареньком Sony Tablet S есть специальная панель, через которую вызываются виджеты, которые могут быть открыты отдельным весящим окном, на подобии, что и в видео.

Comment: @nuts119, почти. прошивка может быть самая обычная, но там кастомный лончер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ нагуглился за 2 минуты.

[Статья на англо-саксонском](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/)

Кратко:

1) Нужен объявленный в манифесте сервис, стартуемый из (например) активити какой-либо.

2) В сервисе добавляем что хотим (ImageView например) методом **addView(View v, LayoutParams params)** в View экрана, коий получаем так:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

3) В манифесте не забываем указать разрешение на подобные манипуляции:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Ответ гуглится второй строчкой по запросу:

```
show view over any activity android
```

Comment: Согласен! Писал всплывашку поверх всех окон! https://github.com/dakatso/PopupCrouton

Comment: @katso, прикольно! Надо будет заюзать у себя)

Answer (score 4):

Ответ такой. Переписывайте логику на Фрагменты, а свою "панельку" отображайте тоже в виде Фрагмента. В итоге этот фрагмент-панель будет всегда виден, например, внизу, а все остальные меняйте.

Comment: @xTIGRx, посмотртел ролик, есть мысли, но как-то не хочется Вам помогать. Вы наверное не знаете, но Вам здесь никто ничего не должен. Научитесь уважать людей, которые тратят своё время, пытаясь Вам помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Как мне видится - это приложение лончер (100%). А постоянно всплывающая картинка - какой-нибудь кастомный Toast.