# Изображение поверх стандартной камеры Android/Ios

Tags: android, ios

Добрый день!

Такой вопрос, как я понимаю, в андройде возможно как-то отображать что-то поверх стандартных приложений (меня интересует камера). ([Работа поверх стандартных приложений Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/238903/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-android))

Собственно сабж, подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно для реализации этого? Что-то я совсем не придумал, как к этой теме подойти.

P.S: если есть знающие люди, был бы премного благодарен за ответ по аналогичному вопросу для Ios.

Спасибо!

Comment: Вот тут немного инфы о том, как отображать что-то поверх чего-то чужого http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/376170/17609

Comment: что то я вопрос не понял - положите просто вью поверх камеры и все